# Magic Arena - Certain deck formats not listed when creating new deck

Tags: pc, magic-the-gathering-arena

When I create a new deck this is the entire selection of options I get to choose from for deck formats.

As you can see there is no options for either **Historic Brawl** or **Historic Pauper**

**AVAILABLE DECK TYPES**

[image: Missing Formats 01 - Magic Arena]

[image: Missing Formats 02- Magic Arena]

---

I simply assumed that these where not options in the game at present until one day I opened an existing deck and realized I could change its format to **Historic Brawl**.

I can then remove all cards and create a new Brawl deck.

[image: Historic Brawl - Magic Arena]

---

The words *Wot da fook* come to mind.

**QUESTIONS**

1. Are these options available currently, in the past or have they been removed?
2. Is there a way to choose these deck formats when creating a new deck and how?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware they're only available for events. It's odd that you can edit an older deck but can't create a new deck, though I assume something in the game's code allows you to turn a deck that's at least as old as one of these events into one of those event decks. I'm not sure if this is intentional or a bug.

Comment: I'm inclined to think the bug is not allowing creating a new deck with any format. There's no reason not to let the player build in a particular format regardless of which events are on.

Comment: The key fact here is that I can create historic decks and play with them against my friends. One of my friends however cannot play with us because he doesn't have the ability to create a historic deck.

Comment: I would probably submit a support request. Either it's a bug or just something confusing they should be able to help with.